# I can't log in to `wp-admin` after changing my domain

Tags: login, domain

I created a website using wordpress. I decided to change my domain and bought it using the website: `https://www.aftermarket.pl/`

After buying a domain in the wordpress panel, I took the following steps:

1. Log in to WordPress
2. Click on the Settings menu.
3. Select General.
4. Update these fields with the new domain name:
5. Click Save Changes.

after following these steps I cannot log in to `wp-admin`. Entering through the old domain - `oldsite.com` redirects me to `newsite.com` where I can only see `File not found`.

Comment: How have you set up newsite.com with your web hosts? You'll need to make sure the DNS is configured correctly, and that your host knows that newsite.com should be used as an alias for oldsite.com in their web server software. There's more to it than just changing the domain names in WordPress.

Comment: If you want to change it back to oldsite.com for the moment but can't get in, here's WordPress's page about this: [Changing the site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)